# Tower of Hanoi TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I'm looking to make an algorithm that calculate how many steps need to be taken for the Tower of Hanoi using OOP.

There are two classes, rods and disks. I'm looking to make disks part of a list in each rod instance.

**Error:**

> "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

When I'm trying to append disk instances into the list in rod instances the above error occurred .

I have checked what type error is however I do not think I have used any of the Python's built-in type names.

```
class rod:
    def __init__(self,disks=[]):
        self.diskslist=disks

    def remove_top(self):
        return self.disks.pop(-1)

    def add_to_top(self,disk):
        self.diskslist.extend(disk)

class disk:
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size=size

disks=[]
for i in range(8):
    disks.append(disk(i))
#Generating 8 disks of increasing size

rods=[]
for i in range(3):
    rods.append(rod())
#Generating 3 rods

for i in range(len(disks)):
    rod[0].add_to_top(disks[I])
#Trying to add all the disks to the leftmost rod. This is where I get my type error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
rod[0].add_to_top(disks[I])
```

use

```
rods[0].add_to_top(disks[I])
```

(`rods` instead of `rod`).

Comment: You can decrease chance of making such mistakes by following style guide that suggests naming classes in CapWords convention. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names